# loading data from csv file into key and value dictionary list

Tags: c#, file, dictionary, keyvaluepair

I have a file consisting of a list of text which looks as follows: 
[Example csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQVPj.png)
There csv file has consist of 3 columns. The first columns will always be the length of 5. So I want to loop through the file content, store those first 5 letters as Key and remaining column as value. I am removing comma between them and Substringing as follows to store.

```
 static string line;
   static Dictionary<string, string> stations = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       // Dictionary<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> stations = new Dictionary<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>();
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(".\\ariba_sr_header_2017122816250.csv");

        foreach (var l in lines)
        {
            line = l.Replace(",", "");
            stations.Add(line.Substring(14),line.Substring(14, line.Length-14));

        }

        //read all key and value in file
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in stations)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
            Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

After debug, the output is 
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N35iy.png)
My Expected Result is as follow:
[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1Zm5.png)

Comment: Substring(14) takes all BUT the 14 first. You want Substring(0,14) to get the 14 first. And why 14??

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
        var stations = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\22.txt");

        foreach (var l in lines)
        {
            var lsplit = l.Split(',');
            if (lsplit.Length > 1)
            {
                var newkey = lsplit[0];
                var newval = lsplit[1] + lsplit[2];
                stations[newkey] = newval;
            }
        }

        //read all key and value in file
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in stations)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " = " + item.Value);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Not exactly the output you expected, but hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any `KeyValuePair` here. You have

```
 00021,00014,Ordered
 00021,00026,Ordered
 00024,00036,Ordered
 ...
```

and you want

```
 00021
 00021
 00024
 000014Ordered 
 000026Ordered
 000036Ordered 
 ...
```

outcome which seems to be `IEnumerable<string>`. You can try *Linq* for this

```
var result = File
  .ReadLines(".\\ariba_sr_header_2017122816250.csv")
  .Line(line => line.Split(','))
  .SelectMany(items => new string[] {
     items[0],
    $"0{items[1]}{items[2]}" })
  .OrderBy(item => item.Length);

foreach (var item in result)
  Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Here we `Split` each line like `00021,00014,Ordered` into separate `items`: {00021, 00014, Ordered}`anf then combine them back with a help of`SelectMany`. We want

1. `00021` which is `items[0]`
2. `000014Ordered` which is `0` + `items[1]` + `items[2]`

Finally we want to have short items first - `OrderBy(item => item.Length)`